# How to get array loop data in servlet from ajax call data parameters?

Tags: javascript, ajax, servlets

I am getting loop data from for loop and pass these values to servlet for saving.So,i want to make a ajax call from my page to servlet and unable to send this loop data to servlet in ajax data parameters.Please help me where i have to do changes.For all help thanks in advance.

```
   function saveAddedSubjects(totalSubjectsNo){
     var year=document.getElementById("selectYear").value;
     alert(year);
     var totalSubjectsNo=document.getElementById("numOfSubjects").value;
     var subject=[];
       for(var i=1;i<=totalSubjectsNo;i++){
         subject[i]=document.getElementById("subject"+i).value;
         console.log(subject[i]);
       }

       $.ajax({
       type : 'POST',
       url : "saveAddedSubjects",
       data : {
        "subjects[i]" : subject[i],
        "year" :year,
        "totalNum":totalSubjectsNo,
       },
      success : function(data, status) {
        alert(status);
    }
});

}
```

I am getting ajax call success,but subjects[] data shows null.

Comment: Please respond anyone.

Comment: i solved the above problem like this.Instead of passing parameters in ajax to servlet,i  postData like below. function saveAddedSubjects(totalSubjectsNo){
 var year=document.getElementById("selectYear").value;
 alert(year);
 var postData = $('#ajaxform').serializeArray();

 $.ajax({
  type : 'POST',
  url : "saveAddedSubjects",
  data : postData,
  success : function(data, status) {
   alert(status);
  }
 });
}